# How can i create a tree like diagram from a file?

Tags: python, diagram, flowchart

I have a file composed of links between objects:

```
object1 obj
```

Comment: Your file seems to be an adjacency list. Look into the `networkx` library for Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `networkx` for this. What you have is a a file of 'links' which in networkx are called 'edges'. In your case you can make use of the `read_adjlist` function.

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.read_adjlist('yourfile')
```

You can then print the graph using libs like `matplotlib` or `graphviz`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
nx.draw(g)
plt.draw
plt.show()
```

If you want your graph to be prettier or have a specific layouts have fun trying out graphviz, sadly I'm super bad at it so you'll have to dig it by yourself ;)

Comment: I just checked this and it looks promising. I tried to install it from pip and git clone but it didn't worked so i downloaded the .tar.gz and after some tweak i finally installed it. But i can't import the function in my code, the module is not detected.

Comment: The import work, i need to specifie the version 3 of python before launching the script, i will try to play with the tool now